# ExtJs 5.0 : forEach on Array of Objects not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, foreach, extjs5

I've a simple model -

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.String'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'currentA'
        },
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'currentB'
        },
        {
            name: 'A'
        },
        {
            name: 'B'
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is some operation that I'm doing on the data for that model-

```
 onBeforeRender: function(component, eOpts) {
    var mystore = Ext.getStore('Mystore');
    mystore.load({
        callback: function(){
            var entity = headerStore.getAt(0);
            var bs = entity.data.B;
            var as = entity.data.A;
            var currentB = entity.data.currentB;
            var currentA = entity.data.currentA;

            bs.forEach(function(record) {
                // do some operations
            });
            as.forEach(function(record) {
                // do some other operations
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now, when iterating over variable "bs", which is clearly an array of objects, IE 8 complains

**"Object doesn't support this property or method"**

for the forEach function. This works fine in Chrome.

Here is the json for the model -

```
{
  "currentA": "a",
  "currentB": "b",
  "A": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
  "B": [
    {
      "name": "b",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is IE not able identify it as an array?

Comment: Mystore is the store for the Model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.each`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-each) from `Ext.Array`, because **IE8** does not support [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)

```
Ext.Array.each(bs, function(record) {
});

Ext.Array.each(as, function(record) {
});
```

`[].forEach` does not depend on ExtJS version because this is JS Array's method which was added in `ES5` standard. From [`this link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) you can see which browser supports `forEach` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because IE8 doesn't implement `forEach` on arrays.

Use `Ext.Array.forEach`.

Comment: the same code has been working in IE 8 with extjs 4.2

Comment: You may have been including some other library.

Comment: I don't see any external library involved. Anyways it's not a problem at the moment. Was just curious.